# Cannot "print" random forest model when loaded into R

Tags: r

I seem to have ran into a problem recently when I load a random forest model into R. Normally when I generate a random forest model using the `randomForest` package, I am able to call on the model itself or use the `print` function to have a nice summary of the model, such as coefficient of determination, number of trees, etc.

For example:

```
test = na.omit(airquality)

RF = randomForest(Ozone ~ Temp + Month + Day, data = test)
RF #or print(RF)
```

The output is:

```
Call:
  randomForest(formula = Ozone ~ Temp + Month + Day, data = test) 
          Type of random forest: regression
                 Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 1

      Mean of squared residuals: 479.4724
                % Var explained: 56.3
```

However, when I save my model RF in R as an .RData file and load it into R,  I can no longer call on the function and get the summary as above. Instead I print out every single list member contained in `str(RF)`.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you load the relevant package as well

Comment: @Dason I do not. Apparently that is what causes the problem. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One must load the `randomForest` package with the `library()` function prior to printing the model once you've read it from disk in order to have it use the specialized version of `print()` that works with a random forest model object.

```
data(airquality)
library(randomForest)
test <- na.omit(airquality)

rfModel <- randomForest (Ozone ~ Temp + Month + Day, data = test)
rfModel
saveRDS(rfModel,"./data/rfModel.rds")
```

At this point if you exit R and restart, the following sequence of commands will print the object as a list.

```
rfModel2 <- readRDS("./data/rfModel.rds")
rfModel2
```

[image]

After loading the `randomForest` package, the model will print as expected.

```
library(randomForest)
rfModel2
```

[image]

Comment: Wow it had not occurred to me that I needed to load the package. It all makes sense now. That also explains the reason why `predict()` doesn't work on a randomForest class object without loading the package first. Thank you very much!